# Can't span width of date plot to linewidth

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, dateplot

**Aim:**

Set the width of a plot to `\linewidth`.

**Current Status:**

Setting the `width` option of the `axis` environment to `\linewidth` yields the `Dimension too large.` error. And indeed, in the resulting document the plot doesn't span the whole line width.

**Question:**

Is there an error in my code or is it a bug?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, row sep=\\]{
   2015-11-11 14:00, 0.2\\
   2015-11-11 14:01, 0.217\\
   2015-11-11 14:02, 0.255\\
   2015-11-11 14:03, 0.288\\
   2015-11-11 14:06, 0.58\\
   2015-11-11 14:07, 0.91\\
   2015-11-11 14:08, 1.02\\
   2015-11-11 14:10, 1.05\\
   2015-11-11 14:12, 0.92\\
   2015-11-11 14:13, 0.78\\
   2015-11-11 14:15, 0.56\\
   2015-11-11 14:17, 1.1\\
}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
      height={5cm},
      width={\linewidth},
      xmin={2015-11-11 14:00},
      xmax={2015-11-11 14:20},
      ytick={0.25,0.5,0.75,1},
      yticklabels={,,,,,,,,},
      date coordinates in=x,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      xticklabel={\hour:\minute\,Uhr},
      xtick={2015-11-11 14:05,2015-11-11 14:10,2015-11-11 14:15},
      enlarge y limits=0.2,
      enlarge x limits=0.1,
      grid,
   ]
      \addplot[smooth,blue,line width=1pt] table  {\datatable};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interestingly, if you change all the dates from 2015 to 2007, the error message goes away.  OTOH, the width is still not \linewidth, but that's just normal pgfplots behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dateplot` lib needs to map the date range to integers (TeX has no longs...). In order to make the best use of the available, limited, data range, it uses `date ZERO` to calibrate the numbers.

If you set `date ZERO` to any date which is close to your data range, the plot is fine.

The actual scaling needs `scale only axis` as `pgfplots` only supports precise scaling of axis rectangle (using a constant guess for the axis descriptions otherwise). In addition, you may want to use `trim axis left,trim axis right` as options to the `tikzpicture` in order to clip away any bounding-box artifacts on the left or and the right. Finally, you should use `\noindent` before the picture (for left alignment) and strip the trailing whitespace after `\end{tikzpicture}` to avoid a spurious space (a common LaTeX problem).

Taking all these changes, I arrive at

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, row sep=\\]{
   2015-11-11 14:00, 0.2\\
   2015-11-11 14:01, 0.217\\
   2015-11-11 14:02, 0.255\\
   2015-11-11 14:03, 0.288\\
   2015-11-11 14:06, 0.58\\
   2015-11-11 14:07, 0.91\\
   2015-11-11 14:08, 1.02\\
   2015-11-11 14:10, 1.05\\
   2015-11-11 14:12, 0.92\\
   2015-11-11 14:13, 0.78\\
   2015-11-11 14:15, 0.56\\
   2015-11-11 14:17, 1.1\\
}\datatable

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
   \begin{axis}[
      height={5cm},
      width={\linewidth},
      xmin={2015-11-11 14:00},
      xmax={2015-11-11 14:20},
      ytick={0.25,0.5,0.75,1},
      yticklabels={,,,,,,,,},
      date coordinates in=x,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      xticklabel={\hour:\minute\,Uhr},
      xtick={2015-11-11 14:05,2015-11-11 14:10,2015-11-11 14:15},
      enlarge y limits=0.2,
      enlarge x limits=0.1,
      grid,
      date ZERO=2015-11-00,
      scale only axis,
   ]
      \addplot[smooth,blue,line width=1pt] table  {\datatable};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]